# Is there a more elegant way of using a 'while loop' without having to define variables outside the 'while loop' first?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm very much new to Stackoverflow and Python(3) so excuse any errors I've made! This is the code I wrote so far:

```
print("""You will need to enter your name so we can make a reservation!
(Use Enter ↵ to confirm)""")

user_firstname = str(input("What is your first name? "))
user_lastname = str(input("What is your last name?  "))
confirm_username = str(input("Is your name " + user_firstname + " " + user_lastname + " ? (y/n) "))[0]

while not confirm_username == "y":
    user_firstname = str(input("What is your first name? "))
    user_lastname = str(input("What is your last name?  "))
    confirm_username = str(input("Is your name " + user_firstname + " " + user_lastname + " ? (y/n) "))[0]
else:
    user_name = user_firstname + " " + user_lastname
```

As you can see in my example I have to state some variables twice (user_firstname, user_lastname & confirm_username). Once before the while loop and once within the while loop. I was wondering if there is a more elegant, less bulky way of writing this code? Any other optimization suggestions are very much welcome as well!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Python equivalent of C's `do`/`while`, which is just a `while True:` infinite loop that ends with an `if condition: break`:

```
while True:
    user_firstname = input("What is your first name? ")
    user_lastname = input("What is your last name?  ")
    confirm_username = input("Is your name " + user_firstname + " " + user_lastname + " ? (y/n) ")[0]
    if confirm_username == "y":
        break
user_name = user_firstname + " " + user_lastname
```

Note: I removed the `str()` wrapping around your `input` calls; `input` already returns `str`, so the wrapping is pointless.

Comment: my favorite "input + validation loop" idiom. some people think `while True` is a crime against humanity, but I prefer it any day over an exact code-duplication of several lines.

Answer (score 1):

`while True` infinite loop, when done BREAK!!

```
print("""You will need to enter your name so we can make a reservation!
(Use Enter ↵ to confirm)""")

user_firstname = str(input("What is your first name? "))
user_lastname = str(input("What is your last name?  "))

while True:
  confirm_username = str(input("Is your name " + user_firstname + " " + user_lastname + " ? (y/n) "))[0]
  if confirm_username == "y":
    user_name = user_firstname + " " + user_lastname
    break
```

Comment: This works except it doesn't ask to renew the input of user_firstname and user_lastname. Therefore Shadowranger takes the cake, thank you anyway :)